# Weakly convergence characterization for $l^p$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

For $1 \leq p < \infty$, let $\{x_n\}$ be a bounded sequence in $l^p$ and $x$ belong in $l^p$. Show that $\{ x_n \} \rightharpoonup x$ in $l^p$ if and only if it converges componentwise, that is, for each index $k$,
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n^k =x^k  \text{ where } x_n = ( x_n^1, x_n^2, ...) \text{ and } x= (x^1, x^2...).$$

**I try like this:** but I think this is true only if $x_n$ converge strongly not weakly. Any solution for this problem?

$"\Rightarrow"$

Let $(x^n)=(x_1^n, x_2^n,..., x_j^n...) \rightharpoonup x=(x_1, x_2,..., x_j,..)$ a bounded sequence in $l^p$

\begin{align*}
\Rightarrow & ||x^n - x||_p < \epsilon\\
& \sum\limits_{j=1}^{\infty} |x_j^n - x_j|^p < \epsilon
\end{align*}

Fix $j :$ $$ |x_j^n - x_j|^p < \sum\limits_{j=1}^{\infty} |x_j^n - x_j|^p < \epsilon$$
$$\Rightarrow |x_j^n - x_j|^p <\epsilon$$
$$\Rightarrow \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} x_j^n = x_j \ \forall j$$

$"\Leftarrow"$ need help

Comment: For $\Rightarrow$, you cannot assume your convergence is a strong one. Rather use that $x'(x^n)$ converges for every $x' \in (\ell^p)'$. In particular, what does this say for the dual element which maps $x$ to its kth element $x_k$ (represented by $e_k \in \ell^q$).

Comment: In the case $p=1$, *I think* the result (for weak or strong convergence, which [are equivalent](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/42609/strong-and-weak-convergence-in-ell1) in this particular case) is false. Consider the sequence $(e_n)_n$ where $e_n^k=1$ if $k=n$ and $0$ otherwise. This sequence is in $\ell^1$, is bounded, and converges to 0 pointwise, but [it doesn't converge weakly](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/303758/a-sequence-converging-weakly-in-ellp-for-p-1-and-failing-to-converge-wea?lq=1) to 0 in $\ell^1$. I'm almost certainly wrong here, but can't see why.

Comment: Some of your indices are off: You write $x= (x^1, x^1, \dots)$. Your reasoning for your proof doesn't match the definitons above (n sometimes as a lower, sometimes as an upper limit).

Comment: @NateRiver You're not wrong. In $\ell^1$ that condition characterises weak$^{\ast}$-convergence viewing $\ell^1$ as the dual of $c_0$.

Comment: @DanielFischer Ah ok thanks. Now I got it.

Comment: I corrected the indexing in the problem statement (e.g., the second sentence in Roland's comment) but not in the attempted answer.  Furthermore, the textbook from which the question is taken actually has $1 < p <\infty$.

Answer (score 4):

Your reasoning is wrong. Your assumption is that $\{x_n\}_{n\in\mathbb N}$ converges weakly to $x$ and not in the norm of the space $l^p.$

Necessity: if $\{x_n\}_{n\in\mathbb N}$ converges weakly to $x$, then by the standard duality $(l^p)^*\cong l^q$ where $1/p+1/q=1.$ In this case
$e_k(x_n)\underset{n\to \infty}{\longrightarrow} e_k(x)$ yields componentwise convergence.

Sufficiency: Let us write $\langle y,x\rangle=y(x)$ for $x\in l^p$ and $y\in l^q.$ Let us choose $y\in l^q$ and $\epsilon>0$ arbitrary. Then there exists (why) $k\in \mathbb N$ such that $\|y-y^{(k)}\|_q<\frac{\epsilon}{2M}$ where $y^{(k)}$ is the projection of $y$ to the subspace spanned by vectors $e_1,\ldots,e_k$ and $M=\sup_{n\in\mathbb N}\|x-x_n\|_p.$
\begin{align}
|\langle y,x-x_n\rangle| \leq |\langle y-y^{(k)},x-x_n\rangle|+|\langle y^{(k)},x-x_n\rangle|.
\end{align}
By applying Holder inequality we obtain
$$
|\langle y-y^{(k)},x-x_n\rangle|\leq \|y-
y^{(k)}\|_q \cdot \|x-x_n\|_p<\frac{\epsilon}{2}$$
Since $\{x_n\}_{n\in\mathbb N}$ converges to $x$ componentwise and since $y^{(k)}$ has only finitely many nonzero components, there exists $k'\in \mathbb N$ such that
$|\langle y^{(k)},x-x_n\rangle|<\frac{\epsilon}{2}$ for all $n\geq k'.$

Remark: you do not need to assume that $\{x_n\}_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is bounded since every weakly convergent sequence is always bounded as a quick consequence of the principle of the uniform boudnedness.

Comment: In other words, $y^{(k)}$ (is this the same as $\tilde y$?) is the sequence $y$ truncated at position $k$. I think that it doesn't hurt to write down $\langle y,x \rangle = \sum_{i=1}^\infty \overline y_n x_n$ (since neither of them is in $\ell^2$ in general). Note that this proof only works for $p>1$ which implies $q<\infty$ - for the sup norm we can't find a $k$ for $y^{(k)}$

Comment: Thank you. I swapped all $\tilde y$ by $y^{(k)}$.

Comment: We do need boundedness (as a background assumption) for the implication "component-wise $\Rightarrow$ weak"

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/239862/boundedness-and-pointwise-convergence-imply-weak-convergence-in-ellp?rq=1) is a proof for the characterization for the *weak convergence* in the case $p\in (1,+\infty)$.

Now, the result you are trying to prove (that the sequence $(x_n)_n$ converges *strongly* to $x\in \ell^p$ if and only if it converges pointwise and is bounded) is false for $p>1$. The counter-example in this case is the sequence $(e_n)_n$ such that for all $k,n$, 
$$
e_n^k=
\begin{cases}
1 & k=n\\
0 & k\neq n
\end{cases}
$$ 
You can see this sequence is in $\ell^p$, is bounded (by 2), and it converges pointwise to $0\in \ell^p$, but does not converge strongly to $0$ in $\ell^p$.

Answer (score 1):

By def'n, $(x(n))_n$ converges weakly to $x$ iff $(f(x(n))_n$ converges to $f(x)$ for every $f\in l_p^*.$ To prove that a bounded sequence $x(n)_n=(<x(n)_i>_i)_n$ converges weakly to $<x_i>_i$ iff $(x(n)_i)_n$ converges to $x_i$ for each $i$ ,we have:(1) Necessity.For each $i$ let $f_i(<y_i>_i)=y_i$ for all $<y_i>_i\in l_p.$ Then $x_i=f_i(x)=\lim_{n \to \infty} f_i (x(n))=x(n)_i.$ (2) Sufficiency. For $m\in N$: For  $y=<y_i>_i\in l_p$ let $$(j\leq m\implies(y|_m)_j=x_j)\;\land \;(j>m \implies (y|m)_j=0.$$ $$\text { For } (f\in l_p^*\; \land \;  y\in l_p) \text { let }\; f|_m(y)=f(y|m).$$  We use the facts that $$(a)\quad \forall x\in l_p \;(\lim_{m\to \infty}\|x-x|m\|=0;$$ $$ (b)\quad \forall f\in  l_p^*\;(\lim_{m\to \infty}\|f|_m-f\|=0.$$ Now take any $f\in l_p^*$:  Given $e>0$ take $m$  large enough that  $\|x-x|m\|<e$ and $\|f-f|m\|<e.$ Now take $n$ large enough that $n'>n\implies  \forall j\leq m\; (|x_j-x(n')_j|<e/m ).$ Then $n'>n\implies$ $$ |f(x)-f(x(n'))|= |f(x|_m-x(n')|_m)+ (f-f|m) (x-x(n')|\leq$$ $$\leq e \|f\| +\|f-f|_m\|\cdot (\|x\|+\|x(n')\|)\leq$$ $$\leq e\|f\|+\|f-f|m\|\cdot(\|x\|+K)$$ where $ K=\sup_{i\in N}\|x(i)\|.$ Letting $n \to \infty$ we have $\lim_{n\to \infty}$      $\sup_{n'>n}$ $ |f(x)-f(x(n')|\leq e$ $ \|f\|+2 \|f-f|_m\|\cdot K.$ Now letting $m\to \infty,$ by (b) we have $\lim_{n\to  \infty} \sup_{n'>n}|f(x)-f(x(n))|\leq e.$  Since $e>0$ is arbitrary, we are done.

Note that the condition $K<\infty$ is necessary. Note that we also used $f|_m(x)=f(x|_m)$ which may help to explain one of the lines above.